# Difference between two batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I got a batch script with a block of code as:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem US locale, ie: 'Thu 12/02/2015'
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/ " %%m in ("%date%") do set /A "n=(3*((1%%m)%%100-1))"
echo %n%
pause
```

and while I was trying to understand it, I landed writing it myself as:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem US locale, ie: 'Thu 12/02/2015'
for /F "tokens=2 delims=/ " %%m in ("%date%") do set /A "n=3*(%%m-1)"
echo %n%
pause
```

Since both returns 33 as output, can anyone please help me understand the logic behind `"n=(3*((1%%m)%%100-1))"` and the difference between both the blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
3*((1%%m)%%100-1)
```

`%%m` is `12` in this example, resulting in

```
3*((112)%%100-1)
```

let's get rid of the redundant parantheses and add some spaces for better readabiltiy:

```
3 * ( 112 %% 100 ) - 1
```

evaluated:

```
3 * (     12     ) - 1
```

`%%` is the "Modulo" Operator - it gives back the rest when dividing the first number throug the second one (112 Modulo 100 is (1*100) rest 12) (NOTE: if you try this on commandline instead of inside a batchfile, use a single `%` only)

This seems to be ridiculous, but think, your number isn't `12`, but `09`. Numbers starting with Zero are handled as octal, but 09(octal) isn't a valid number, so you'll get a Syntax error.

Same walkthrough with `09` instead of `12`:

```
3*((109)%%100-1)
3 * ( 109 %% 100 ) - 1
3 * (      9     ) - 1
```

The last line without the Modulo trick would be:

```
3 * (     09     ) - 1
```

As `09` is not a valid number (there is no `9` in octal numbers), this wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a great explanation... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the digit-group being processed is "08" or "09".

Batch assumes that a leading "0" means that the following string is **octal** not **decimal** and objects to 8 or 9 since they are not octal digits.

the method prefixes a "1" amking "108" or "109" which are bot valid **decimal** numbers that do not start "0" and hence will be interpreted as **decimal**.

Since 100 is added to each of the numbers 01..12 then you add 100, you need to remove that 100, so `%%100` does that (calculate mod-100 = 1..12)

Another way would be to subtract 100, obviously.

(assuming the group is a **month**. If it's a *day** as it would appear, the same argument applies, but the limits are 01..31 or 1..31.)